# Nivo Slider wont appear

Tags: jquery, html, slider, nivo-slider

Im trying to apply the Nivo Slider to the top of my webpage.
I did a test page, and it worked fine. I used the same code and dumped it into one of my div tags on the real document, and it wont appear at all. The div tag is with in a couple of div tags. maybe thats the issue but i really dont know! I  need some help.

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XT9BW/)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="nivo-slider.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/default/default.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script src="jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```
  <div class="slider-wrapper theme-default">
    <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
        <img src="images/toystory.jpg" alt="" />
        <a href="http://dev7studios.com"><img src="images/up.jpg" alt="" title="#htmlcaption" /></a>
        <img src="images/walle.jpg" alt="" title="This is an example of a caption" />
        <img src="images/nemo.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
</div>
<div id="htmlcaption" class="nivo-html-caption">
    <strong>This</strong> is an example of a <em>HTML</em> caption with <a href="#">a link</a>.
</div>


  </div>
```

end of body

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#slider').nivoSlider();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your order of script src is not balanced i must say, you should put jquery up and slider down then see if works:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: There should have been no doubt in this answer at all.   jQuery MUST load before any jQuery plugins or code.